# Why do some web apps use intermediate page before redirection?

Tags: language-agnostic

After editing an article or logging in some forums or CMS, you get a intermediate page that say something like "Thanks for X, if you didn't redirect in few seconds click here".

Why they do that instead of going directly to the page?

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons to do this; and most of them are silly:

1. The developer could simply not know how to set up server side redirects. (Silly)
2. The web application could be set up in such a fashion that certain actions that require a redirect don't allow the taking of a redir= parameter, of something of the kind (Much the same as 1, and still silly)
3. The developer could be trying to squeeze more ad impressions out of the visitors on the intermediate page. (Extremely silly)
4. The web app could be operating under some extreme "safe mode" that doesn't allow server-side redirects (Yep, you guessed it, silly.)
5. The developer could wish to be very explicit about what exactly the user just did, so as to be sure that the user knows what just happened. (At face value, this seems sensible. But whereas users literally couldn't read a status message if their life depended on it; silly.)
6. **Edit:** Using it instead of 303 Found to implement [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). (Silly, see all of the above.)

**Edit:** When I say most of them are silly, I don't mean to say that some of them are silly, and some are not. I mean to say that some of them are silly an some are extremely silly.

Comment: thanks , i found also another reason but not silly  :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @3DVector: Actually; using a meta redirect in the PRG pattern covers by 1, 2, 4 *and* 5

Answer (score 0):

I've done it to hide the referer from the target site. So, if you're on:

```
http://host/this/that?some=private;cgi=parameters;that=you+don't+want+exposed
```

Then sending some through a simple redirector will hide that URL and the final target will only see something generic like

```
http://host/redir?u=http://example.com/the-target-url
```

as the referer. Redirector pages can also be used for click tracking.

Answer (score -1):

You usually get that when you perform an `HTML` redirection (using `meta` tag on HTML's header). If you perform a HTTP redirection using header `Location: index.php` you won't get that.

I happen to find that HTML redirection works a little bit better with older mobile browsers so I had to use that instead of HTTP redirection in some projects. Other than that, there is no specific reason to use one of the other. It's just a matter of taste. Maybe the forums you are referring to want you to notice that you are going to be redirected...

Comment: It's not merely a matter of taste: If you insert a meta tag into your page; that doesn't help browsers and caching proxies that might be interested in knowing where your content is; but if you send a 301 Moved Permanently, they can update their bookmarks and caches accordingly.